# How is the best constrained function template selected with concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In a presentation of concepts something like this was shown:

```
template <bidirectional_iterator It>
void sort(It begin, It end);            // #1

template <random_access_iterator It>
void sort(It begin, It end);            // #2
```

```
std::list<int> l{};
sort(l.begin(), l.end()); // #A  -> calls #1

std::vector<int> v{};
sort(v.begin(), v.end()); // #B  -> calls #2
```

For the call `#A` it's simple: only `sort #1` is viable as the constraint `random_access_iterator` is not satisfied so it calls `#1`.

But for the call `#B` both `sort`s are viable as both constraints (`random_access_iterator` and `bidirectional_iterator` are satisfied). So how is the "more efficient" `sort #2` chosen? The presenter said "it just works".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how is the "more efficient" `sort #2` chosen?

It works because there is a **partial ordering** on constraints (defined by the **subsumes** relation).

`sort #2` (the one with the `randomaccess_iterator`) is *more constrained* than `sort #1` (the one with `bidirectional_iterator`) because `randomaccess_iterator` subsumes `bidirectional_iterator`:

```
template <class It>
concept bidirectional_iterator = requires /*...*/;

template <class It>
concept randomaccess_iterator = bidirectional_iterator<It> && requires /*...*/;
```

To make this work constraints are aware at the language level of conjunctions and disjunctions.

The process for determining if a declaration is more or less constrained than another goes like this: Constraint normalization -> constraint *subsumes* relation -> (defines) constraint partial ordering -> (determines) declarations are more/less constraint relation.

Simplified, normalization is the substitution of the concepts template parameters in the parameter mapping of constraints.

---

Example:

```
template <class T> concept integral        = std::is_integral_v<T>;
template <class T> concept signed_integral = integral<T> && std::is_signed_v<T>;
template <class T> concept integral_4      = integral<T> && sizeof(T) == 4;

void foo_1(integral auto)        // #0
void foo_1(signed_integral auto) // #1 
void foo_1(integral_4 auto)      // #2

auto test1()
{
    foo_1(std::uint16_t{});  // calls #0
    foo_1(std::uint32_t{});  // calls #2

    foo_1(std::int16_t{});   // calls #1
    //foo_1(std::int32_t{}); // error ambiguous between #1 and #2
}
```

- the normal form of `integral` is `std::is_integral_v<T>`
- the normal form of `signed_integral` is `std::is_integral_v<T> ∧ std::is_signed_v<T>`
- the normal form `integral_4` is `std::is_integral_v<T> ∧ sizeof(T) == 4`
- `signed_integral` subsumes `integral`
- `integral_4` subsumes `integral`
- `#1` is more constraint than `#0`
- `#2` is more constraint than `#0`

Example:

```
template <class T> concept integral            = std::is_integral_v<T>;
template <class T> concept signed_integral_sad = std::is_integral_v<T> &&
                                                     std::is_signed_v<T>;
template <class T> concept integral_4_sad      = std::is_integral_v<T> && sizeof(T) == 4;


void foo_2(integral auto)             // #0
void foo_2(signed_integral_sad auto); // #1
void foo_2(integral_4_sad auto);      // #2


auto test2()
{
    foo_2(std::uint16_t{});   // calls #0
    //foo_2(std::uint32_t{}); // error ambiguous between #0 and #2

    //foo_2(std::int16_t{});  // error ambiguous between #0 and #1
    //foo_2(std::int32_t{});  // error ambiguous between #0, #1 and #2
}
```

- the normal form of `integral` is `std::is_integral_v<T>`
- the normal form of `signed_integral_sad` is `std::is_integral_v<T> ∧ std::is_signed_v<T>`
- the normal form `integral_4_sad` is `std::is_integral_v<T> ∧ sizeof(T) == 4`

However there is a rule

> **§13.5.1.2 Atomic constraints [temp.constr.atomic]**
>
> 2. Two atomic constraints, `e1` and `e2`, are identical if they are formed from the same appearance of the same expression [...]

This means that the `std::is_integral_v<T>` atomic expressions from the 3 normal forms are not identical between them because they were not formed from the same expression. So:

- there is no *subsumes* relation
- there is no *more constraint* relation

Which leads to the extra ambiguities.

---

> **§ 13.5.1 Constraints [temp.constr.constr]**
>
> 1. A constraint is a sequence of logical operations and operands that specifies requirements on template arguments. The operands of a
>      logical operation are constraints. There are three different kinds of
>      constraints:
>
>    - (1.1) conjunctions (13.5.1.1)
>    - (1.2) disjunctions (13.5.1.1), and
>    - (1.3) atomic constraints (13.5.1.2).
>
> **§13.5.1.1 Logical operations [temp.constr.op]**
>
> 1. There are two binary logical operations on constraints: conjunction and disjunction. [Note: These logical operations have no corresponding
>      C++ syntax. For the purpose of exposition, conjunction is spelled
>      using the symbol ∧ and disjunction is spelled using the symbol ∨]

> **§13.5.3 Constraint normalization [temp.constr.normal]**
>
> 1. The normal form of an expression E is a constraint (13.5.1) that is defined as follows:
>
>    - (1.1) The normal form of an expression `( E )` is the normal form of
>        `E`.
>    - (1.2) The normal form of an expression `E1 || E2` is the
>        disjunction (13.5.1.1) of the normal forms of `E1` and `E2`.
>    - (1.3) The normal form of an expression `E1 && E2` is the conjunction
>        of the normal forms of `E1` and `E2`.
>    - (1.4) The normal form of
>        a concept-id `C<A1, A2, ..., An>` is the normal form of the
>        constraint-expression of `C`, after substituting `A1, A2, ..., An` for
>        `C`’s respective template parameters in the parameter mappings in each
>        atomic constraint. [...]
>    - (1.5) The normal form of any other
>        expression `E` is the atomic constraint whose expression is `E` and
>        whose parameter mapping is the identity mapping.
> 2. The process of obtaining the normal form of a constraint-expression is called normalization.

> **§13.5.4 Partial ordering by constraints [temp.constr.order]**
>
> 1. A constraint `P` subsumes a constraint `Q` if and only if, for every disjunctive clause `Pi` in the disjunctive normal form
>      <sup>130</sup> of `P`, `Pi` subsumes every conjunctive clause `Qj` in
>      the conjunctive normal form <sup>131</sup> of `Q`, where
>
>    - (1.1) a disjunctive clause `Pi` subsumes a conjunctive clause `Qj`
>        if and only if there exists an atomic constraint `Pia` in `Pi` for
>        which there exists an atomic constraint `Qjb` in `Qj` such that `Pia`
>        subsumes `Qjb`, and
>    - (1.2) an atomic constraint `A` subsumes
>        another atomic constraint `B` if and only if `A` and `B` are identical
>        using the rules described in 13.5.1.2.
>
>    [Example: Let `A` and `B`
>      be atomic constraints (13.5.1.2). The constraint `A ∧ B` subsumes `A`,
>      but `A` does not subsume `A ∧ B`. The constraint `A` subsumes `A ∨ B`,
>      but `A ∨ B` does not subsume `A`. Also note that every constraint
>      subsumes itself. — end example]
> 2. [Note: The subsumption relation defines a partial ordering on constraints. This partial ordering is used to determine
>
>    - (2.1) the best viable candidate of non-template functions (12.4.3),
>    - (2.2) the address of a non-template function (12.5),
>    - (2.3) the matching of template template arguments (13.4.3),
>    - (2.4) the partial ordering of class template specializations (13.7.5.2), and
>    - (2.5) the partial ordering of function
>        templates (13.7.6.2).
>
> — end note]
>
> 3. A declaration `D1` is at least as constrained as a declaration `D2` if
>
>    - (3.1) `D1` and `D2` are both constrained declarations and `D1`’s
>        associated constraints subsume those of `D2`; or
>    - (3.2) `D2` has no associated constraints.
> 4. A declaration `D1` is more constrained than another declaration `D2` when `D1` is at least as constrained as `D2`, and `D2` is not at
>      least as constrained as `D1`.
>
> ---
>
> 130) A constraint is in disjunctive normal form when it is a
>   disjunction of clauses where each clause is a conjunction of atomic
>   constraints. [Example: For atomic constraints `A`, `B`, and `C`, the
>   disjunctive normal form of the constraint `A ∧ (B ∨ C)` is `(A ∧ B) ∨
>   (A ∧ C)`. Its disjunctive clauses are `(A ∧ B)` and `(A ∧ C)`. — end
>   example]
>
> 131) A constraint is in conjunctive normal form when it is a
>   conjunction of clauses where each clause is a disjunction of atomic
>   constraints. [Example: For atomic constraints `A`, `B`, and `C`, the
>   constraint `A ∧ (B ∨ C)` is in conjunctive normal form. Its
>   conjunctive clauses are `A` and `(B ∨ C)`. — end example

Comment: what happens when two concepts are orthogonal? I suppose I'd get an error already when declaring the template with them as two alternatives? Awesome question & answer, maybe some colloquial words to illsutrate what the standard is saying would help those that are not so fluent in standardese

Comment: @idclev463035818 added examples

Comment: you already had my vote. Certainly I'll come back here in the future. I just recently had my first contact with concepts and this answer looks like extremely interesting stuff