# When is a requires clause expression required to be parenthesised? (pun by accident)

Tags: c++, c++20, requires-clause

This gives an error:

```
template <class T, T A, T B>
    requires A > B             // <-- error
class X{};
```

> error: parentheses are required around this expression in a requires
>   clause
>
> ```
> requires A < B
>
>          ~~^~~
>
>          (    )
> ```

Almost all operators give this error (`requires A > B`, `requires A == B`, `requires A & B`, `requires !A`)

However `&&` and `||` seem to work:

```
template <class T, T A, T B>
    requires A && B             // <-- ok
class X{};
```

---

*Testes with gcc trunk and clang trunk (on May 2020) on godbolt. Both compilers give the same results.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `&&` and `||` are treated special here because constraints are aware of conjunctions and disjunctions.

> § 13.5.1 Constraints [temp.constr.constr]
>
> 1. A constraint is a sequence of logical operations and operands that specifies requirements on template arguments. The operands of a
>      logical operation are constraints. There are three different kinds of
>      constraints:
>
>    (1.1) — conjunctions (13.5.1.1),
>      (1.2) — disjunctions
>      (13.5.1.1), and 
>      (1.3) — atomic constraints (13.5.1.2).

They need to be in order to define a partial ordering by constraints.

> **13.5.4 Partial ordering by constraints [temp.constr.order]**
>
> 2. [Note: [...] This partial ordering is used to determine
>
>    - (2.1) the best viable candidate of non-template functions (12.4.3),
>    - (2.2) the address of a non-template function (12.5),
>    - (2.3) the matching of template template arguments (13.4.3),
>    - (2.4) the partial ordering of class template specializations (13.7.5.2), and
>    - (2.5) the partial ordering of function
>        templates (13.7.6.2).
>
> — end note]

Which makes this code work:

```
template <class It>
concept bidirectional_iterator = requires /*...*/;

template <class It>
concept randomaccess_iterator = bidirectional_iterator<It> && requires /*...*/;

template <bidirectional_iterator It>
void sort(It begin, It end);            // #1

template <randomaccess_iterator It>
void sort(It begin, It end);            // #2
```

```
std::list<int> l{};
sort(l.begin(), l.end()); // #A  -> calls #1

std::vector<int> v{};
sort(v.begin(), v.end()); // #B  -> calls #2
```

But for call `#B` even if both `sort`s are viable as both constraints (`randomaccess_iterator` and `bidirectional_iterator` are satisfied) the `sort #2` (the one with the `randomaccess_iterator`) is correctly chosen because it is *more constrained* than `sort #1` (the one with `bidirectional_iterator`) because `randomaccess_iterator` subsumes `bidirectional_iterator`:

See [How is the best constrained function template selected with concepts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634127/how-is-the-best-constrained-function-template-selected-with-concepts/61634128#61634128)

Answer (score 5):

Requires clauses use a special expression grammar to avoid [certain pathological parsing ambiguities](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0730r0.html). As noted [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_clauses), the allowed forms are

- a [primary expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:primary-expression)
- a sequence of primary expressions joined with the operator `&&`
- a sequence of aforementioned expressions joined with the operator `||`